# Error in Torch7 while taking images as input

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I have installed trepl packages still i am getting following error:

torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: ./data.lua:106: bad argument #2 to 'random' (interval is empty)

Can anyone help me in solving this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This [line](https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/e125c4854bea225bf1395bd834d6f305d35f226c/person-detector/data.lua#L106) performs a `math.random(15, 5)` call which fails with PUC Lua (hence the error), but is allowed by LuaJIT. Either use Torch with LuaJIT or open an issue in this repo.

Comment: Sorry I am newbie to torch ,I am trying to run person-detector problem which is provided by torch. Can you please tell me how to use Torch with LuaJIT. Someone suggested me to use Lua5.2 so it will resolve this problem. Now I removed the old version and i installed 5.2 version after installing i tried by using 5.2 version still i am getting same error.

Comment: LuaJIT is currently the default so just follow http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html Alternatively you may want to open an issue on [torch/demos](https://github.com/torch/demos) for this problem with the person-detector / Lua 5.2.